# Redux reducer limitation

Tags: reactjs, redux, storage

I'm currently using React + Redux in my app. When my user login I make all calls to API to stock the data in different reducers.

I recently added a personalized picture that goes into that reducer in base64 format. With that change, if a user has 3/4 pictures if their is a reload, the application reducer where pictures are become empty, as if a limitation was touch.

How should I proceed? One call by webpage? One specific call for the picture page?

Thank you

Comment: localStorage is a better place for large data like images. Or if you have control over the backend, you ensure that the browser can properly cache the images, then you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux state will always be reset, after a refresh. If you want to persist something to stay there after a refresh, you need to use redux-persist, or sessionStorage/localStorage. If you want to make sure that the user info stays up to date, you could make the call, to fetch the user data, in the componendDidMount function of the root component (the app component that gets rendered for each page), so that it gets called after every refresh, on each page.

Comment: Hello, sorry I forgot to mention that I already have redux-persist and this is working well ! But since I store image in it, with the refresh it's not working well on the specific reducer where I store the pictures. I will try in localStorage, maybe it is better. Keep you updated, thank you !